# Retrieve records in mongoDB using bidirectional query

Tags: mongodb, bidirectional-relation

I have two collections - `Tickets` and `Users`. Where a `user` can have one to many `tickets`. The ticket collection is defined as follows

```
Ticket = {_id, ownerId, profile: {name}}
```

The ownerId is used to find all tickets that belong to a specific person. I need to write a query that gets me all **users with no tickets.**

How can i write this query without having to loop through all users, checking if the userID shows up in any Tickets?

Would a bidirectional storage cause me any performance problems ? For example, if i were to change my `users` collection and add an array of `tickets: [ticketID, ticketID2, ...]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the array of tickets being stored in users. As far as I know, Mongo doesn't really have a way to query one collection based on the (lack of) elements in another collection. With the array, though, you can simply do `db.users.find({tickets:[]})`.

Comment: I think i will take this approach. About your query though, if i am looking for 'users without any tickets', does your query read, grab all users where the field tickets exists but does not equal empty ?

Comment: Oh, you're right. I've edited the answer to find users without tickets.

Comment: Yes that does it and i modified it so that it also returns me in the case there are existing users that do not have the `tickets` field to begin with using the suggested `exists: false` idea. Thanks